# my select with two tables dont returns any row

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Im doing a select with two tables but Im not having returned rows.

But If I do my select with just one table(news or pages) it works perfectly.

This is my code:

```
$pdo = conecting();
$read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT title,content FROM news, pages WHERE (title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ?)");
$read->bindValue(1,"%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$read->bindValue(2,"%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$read->execute();
echo '<p>Your search returned <strong>'.$read->rowCOunt().' results!</strong></p>';
if($read->rowCount() <=0){
    echo '<h2>We didnt found any result for your search.</h2>';
}
```

Do you see some reason for this issue?

If I use only one table, Im always returning rows, like this:

`$read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT title, content FROM pages WHERE (title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ?)")`;

OR with just news:

```
$read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT title, content FROM news WHERE (title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ?)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`,` is like using a join, so you are essentially doing `SELECT cols FROM news JOIN pages`.  If both tables have `title` and `content` columns, this will result in an error.  You should turn [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) on while you are developing.

In this case you probably want to use a union.

```
SELECT title, content FROM news WHERE ($clause)
UNION title, content FROM pages WHERE ($clause)
```

Just remember that this will require binding four values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in this case its not correct use two different selects? Is there any advantage in using only a select with the Union?

Comment: @OzzC I don't think there is a huge difference between using two queries or Union.  It may be slightly faster to do one or the other, but I don't think it would make enough of a difference.  Use whichever is easier for you.